# JPA/Hibernate ManyToMany vs two-sided OneToMany/ManyToOne

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I am developing a JavaEE application and I use JPA/Hibernate as a persistence engine. While developing the application, some questions raised to my mind.

The application consists of users and their roles in a N:M relationship. Here is the database subset of the above tables.

[image]

I am relatively new to Hibernate and at first I asked IntelliJ IDEA to generate the mapping for me. What it did was generate the following Java classes:

- UserEntity.java
- RoleEntity.java
- UserXRoleEntity.java
- UserXRoleEntityPK.java

Thus, it generated a mapping for the relation table and two 1:N relationships, one between `user` and `userXrole` and one between `role` and `userXrole`.

After some research, I found that, by using the `@ManyToMany` annotation, I could omit mapping the `userXrole` table into a Java class and just declare it within the annotation as the `@JoinTable`.

So the question is:

- **Why does IntelliJ generate the entities that way**?

Is it just a more generic way that helps generation, or does it have any other advantages. Would you argue in favour of one way or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it just a more generic way that helps generation, or does it have any other advantages.

JPA doesn't know if a table is just a join table, that's why you have to tell it (using `@JoinTable`). The generator might guess, but it will probably only generate `@ManyToMany` if your table names match JPAs defaults.

> Would you argue in favour of one way or the other?

I'd use @ManyToMany if i don't have a reason (finer grained control over lazy/eager fetching maybe?) for separate mapping entities, mostly because less code = less errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you provide any source link stating database naming conventions for JPA?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ - for this case 2.10.4 (page 48 in the pdf)